# $C[0,1]$ with $L^1$ norm is not Banach space.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I want to check that $(C[0,1],∥⋅∥_1)$ is not a Banach space, where $\|f\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f(x)|\,{\rm d}x$.I took $(f_n)_{n \geq 1}$ a sequence in $C[0,1]$ given by:$f_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R},  \ x\rightarrow \begin{cases}
0  & \text{, $\ 0 ≤ x ≤ \frac{1}{2}$}\\[2ex]
(nx-n/2) &\text{, $\frac{1}{2} < x ≤ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n+1}$}  \\[2ex]
1 & \text{, $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n+1} < x ≤ 1$}
\end{cases}$
I want to show that $f_n$ is Cauchy but also that the limit function $f$ is not continuous and hence $∉C([0,1])$. The second part is obvious, since $f$ is not continous at $1/2$.
What I tried is that: Let $n≥m:$
$\begin{align}  \|f_n - f_m\| &= \int_0^1 | f_n(x) - f_m(x) | \ dx \\
&= \int_\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}} | f_n(x) - f_m(x) | \ dx + \int_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m+1}} | f_n(x) - f_m(x) | \ dx\\
&= \int_\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}} | (m-n) |\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) \ dx + \int_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m+1}}  (1-mx+m/2) )\ dx
\end{align}$
                                 I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Small detail: Sholdn't the second point where you "cut" your function $f_n$ in the definition be $1/2+1/n$ and not $1/2+1/(n+1)$? Otherwise, your $f_n$ does not become continuous at that point.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814305/let-v-c0-1-cdot-with-f-int-01fx-dx-consider-the?rq=1)

Comment: [Another similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262265/checking-that-c0-1-cdot-1-is-not-banach?rq=1)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402841/c0-1-is-not-complete-space-with-respect-to-norm-lvert-f-rvert-1-int and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479443/c0-1-with-l1-norm-is-not-banach-space

Comment: There may be less calculation by finding $\|f_n-f\|$ . Then $\|f_n-f_m\|\leq  \|f_n-f\|+\|f-f_m\|.$

Answer (score 7):

It's easier than you think, remember that in order to prove that a sequence is Caushy, you don't need the *exact* distance between two terms, you just need a bound.

You're integrating $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|$ from $1/2$ to $1/2 + \max\left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{m+1}\right)$. We have that the integrand is
$$
|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq |f_n(x)|+|f_m(x)| \leq 1+1 \leq 2
$$
and if you let $m, n \geq N$ for some natural $N$, then the interval you're integrating over is shorter than $1/N$, which means that the result is smaller than $2/N$. Now, given any $\epsilon > 0$, pick an $N\in \Bbb N$ such that $2/N < \epsilon$. The rest should do itself.